# How To Create 16-bit Bitmap From Integer Array?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I've got an integer array which will only contain values that can be represented by 16 bits (values will range from 0-65535). The integer array is several 8-bit images added together such that the sum of all of the top left pixels of each image is the first element of the integer array. I need to create a `Bitmap` object in the `PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale` format, but I'm not sure how to do that. My current code yields a `System.AccessViolationException` when trying to copy the integers into an `IntPtr`.

```
/// <summary>
///     Converts image int data to bitmap image by creating a compatible bitmap and copying
///     the data. This assumes the int array is a 16 bit image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">Image int data.</param>
/// <param name="width">Width of the image.</param>
/// <param name="height">Height of the image.</param>
/// <param name="pixelFormat">Pixel format of the image.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this int[] image, int width, int height, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
{
    // Create a compatible bitmap
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);

    // Copy the bits
    BitmapData bmData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    IntPtr pNative = bmData.Scan0;
    Marshal.Copy(image, 0, pNative, width * height);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmData);

    // Clone into desired format
    Bitmap clone = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), pixelFormat);
    bitmap.Dispose();
    return clone;
}
```

Comment: You are ordering copying of `width * height` `int`s. That is `4 * width * height` bytes. Your bitmap pixel data contains roughly `2 * width * height` bytes, taking into account the rounding up of each stride to the next 4 bytes. Thus your are copying roughly twice more data than the bitmap data can contain, spilling it where it doesn't belong, hence the access violation exception. Start at why your "values that can be represented by 16 bits" are stored in an array of `int`.

Comment: (Not considering the mistake when sizing the buffer and the unclear composition of the content) You may want to use a BitmapSource instead of a Bitmap. GDI+ doesn't support 16 bit GrayScale bitmaps.